# Marker and the cube

Tags: geometry, reachability

If a marker is located in one of the corners of a square cube and we begin to draw according to the following conditions, how many edges of the cube can we cross ?

A) You can cross every edge only once.

B) The marker must not be separated from the cube.

C) The marker can only cross the corners and edges of the cube.

[image: here is the image]

Comment: Wait, do you mean we have to stay on the edges, or we can go onto the faces, but just have to pass over an edge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what the question means, the answer is either 9 or 12 edges per previous answers.  Here are two diagrams.

[image: Cubes]

Comment: Only edges! You can only cross edges @Len

Comment: The answer is 9

Comment: @shayan - OK. I would use the word "traverse" instead of "cross" ;-)

Answer (score 6):

The best you can do is 9. Let's number corners as 1-4 on top, 5-8 on bottom (`i` is connected to `i+4`). You can do:

```
(1-2), (2-3), (3-4), (4-1), (1-5), (5-6), (6-7), (7-8), (8-5)
```

which has 9 edges.

Why is this the best?

As the cube is a graph with 12 edges and 8 vertices and each vertex has a degree of 3. Effectively this means that passing through a vertex "removes" 2 of that degree. The other 1 must be an end of a sequence of vertices and edges. Having 8 "ends" means that you must have 4 sequences of vertices and edges.

As each sequence has at least one edge, by minimizing three of those sequences to a length of one edge, we get that the best we can do is 9 for the fourth sequence.

For a more theoretical approach to that problem have a [look at this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path).

Comment: @shayan It is against the policies puzzling.SE to ask [questions from ongoing contests](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1674/questions-from-on-going-contests)

Comment: oh i didnt know delete your comment plz i dont do this any more :(

Comment: he he ! i just wanted you to be more serious! its not a contest me and my friends are playing! :|

Comment: the xperia c3 will be for the winner for 1 week:| its not a real contest man...:|

Comment: so you were saying... are you sure its right?

Comment: HEY...?@dmg where are u?

Comment: @dmg I think it would be good if you name/link the contest if you think you've found such violation of policy. It helps the rest of us evaluate it. Also, by this policy, shouldn't we lock the question for the time of the contest?

Comment: @BmyGuest OP said it himself, but deleted the comment. I was unable to find the contest, which leaves us somewhere in the grey area. And yes, if proven a contest question, the question is locked and answers are soft-deleted.

Comment: Why are you doing this its not a contest!! Its just a freeking game with my friends! @dmg

Comment: @shayan Don't get hot and relax - and stay polite. Have you read the article dmg has linked? That should give you all the reasons and explanations. If this was all a mistake and no contest, simply forget it.

Comment: @shayan Because you said it yourself. Deleting your comment, does not mean that moderators can't see it.

Comment: @dmg i said i will win a xperia c3 but its not a contest! its just a game that me and my friends play and anyone who wins gets one's mobile phone for 1 week! just this nothing so serious!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can hit all 12 edges. Path (faces) is: top-left-back-top-right-back-bottom-right-front-bottom-left-front-top

Comment: i dont think so cuz i said: you can cross from each edge  only once.